# Invertibility of a Rank-One Update of a Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-rank

I want to find a necessary and sufficient condition for $B = A + x \, y^\top$ to be invertible, where $A$ is assumed to be symmetric and $x, \, y \, \in \mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$. I know that the following holds

> **Theorem**. Let $E = I - \alpha \, u \, v^\top$ be a rank-one modification of the identity $I$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ and $u, \, v \, \in \mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$. Then, $E$ is invertible if and only if $\alpha \, u^\top v -1 \ne 0$. Furthermore, $E^{-1} = I - \beta \, u \, v^\top$ with $\beta = \alpha/(\alpha \, u^\top v - 1) $.

Now, I want to find a necessary and sufficient condition for invertiblity of $B$ by using this theorem. I suspect that it should be the positive definiteness of $A$, but I am having a little bit of difficulty to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, then $A+xy^\top=A(I+\xi y^\top)$ with $\xi=A^{-1}x$. Therefore, $A+xy^\top$ is invertible iff so is $I+\xi y^\top$, and you can use your general criterion.

If $A$ is not invertible, then $A=a_1b_1^\top+...+a_rb_r^\top$ with $r=\mathrm{rank}\,A$, in particular $r<n$. Then $A+xy^\top=a_1b_1^\top+...+a_rb_r^\top+xy^\top$ has rank $r$ iff either $x$ is in the linear span of the $a_i's$ or $y$ is the the linear span of the $b_i$'s, otherwise it has rank $r+1$. Hence, if $A$ is not invertible, $A+xy^\top$ is invertible iff $A$ has rank $n-1$ and $y^\top$ does not belong to the linear span of the rows of $A$ and $x$ does not belong to the linear span of the columns of $A$.

The condition slightly simplifies if $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: (+1) Thanks Giulio for the attention. However, I am looking for **one** necessary and sufficient condition. The first part you said, proves the sufficiency of $A$ being invertible and $\xi^t y - 1 \ne 1$. Can't we some how conclude that if $B$ is invertible then $A$ is invertible, which implies that $(I + \xi y^t)$ should be invertible?

Comment: We cannot conclude that $A$ is invertible from $B$ being invertible. E.g., take $A=diag(1,1,...,1,0)$ and $x=y=(0,....,0,1)^t$. We can however conclude that $A$ is either invertible or has rank $n-1$ (i.e., only fails to be invertible that much)

Comment: By the way, what are $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s? Did you write an SVD decomposition of $A$?

Comment: Yes, if you like it comes from the SVD. But you don't need to invoke that. Let $r$ be the rank of $A$, which by definition means that the row span of $A$ is generated by $r$ l.i. vectors $b_1^t,...,b_r^t$. Therefore, the $j$th row of $A$ is $a_1^{(j)}b_1^t+\dots+a_r^{(j)}b_r^t$, for some scalars $a_i^{(j)}$, $j=1,...,n,$ $i=1,...,r$. This is equivalent to $A=a_1b_1^t+\dots+a_rb_r^t$ by defining the $r$ vectors $a_i=(a_i^{(1)},...,a_i^{(n)})^t$ for $i=1,...,r$.

Comment: Take a look at user1551's answer. He made **one** simple necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: Then you can accept his answer, it is equivalent to mine but maybe formulated better for your purposes (+1 BTW).

Answer (score 2):

The [rank-one update formula for determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) is $\det(A+xy^T)=\det(A)+y^T\operatorname{adj}(A)x$. Since $\det(A)+y^T\operatorname{adj}(A)x=\det(A)(1+y^TA^{-1}x)$ when $A$ is invertible, the followings are equivalent:

- $A+xy^T$ is invertible;
- $\det(A)+y^T\operatorname{adj}(A)x\ne0$;
- ($A$ is invertible and $1+y^TA^{-1}x\ne0$) or ($A$ is singular and $y^T\operatorname{adj}(A)x\ne0$).

This equivalence is valid over any field. Whether $A$ is real symmetric is irrelevant.

Comment: (+1) Really nice and clean answer. :) Thanks for the attention.

Comment: However, I think that invertibility of $B$ does not imply that of $A$ as mentioned in the comments of Giulio's answer. So, you should probably modify case 1. Indeed, case 1 is sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: and by the way, is there a general formula for the inverse of $B$ when $A$ is not invertible? When $A$ is invertible, we have the Sherman-Morrison formula.

Comment: 1 and 2 are not two equivalent conditions. They are two mutually exclusive cases in one condition. I have rewritten my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is invertible, the invertibility of $B$ is equivalent to $1 + y^\top A^{-1} x \ne 1$ and $B^{-1}$ will be given by the [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula.

$$B^{-1} = (A + x \, y^\top)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{A^{-1} x \, y^\top A^{-1}}{1 + y^\top A^{-1} x}$$

If $A$ is positive definite, so all of its eigen-values are positive, so $\lambda_i > 0, \quad i=1, \dots, n$. This implies that $\det A = \lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n \ne 0$, which is equivalent to $A$ being invertible. Consequently, the Sherman-Morrison formula also holds when $A$ is positive definite.